# SetPrincipal (@User.Identity.Name) from a cookie in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I like to know how I can set the `@User.Identity.Name` via a cookie when a user clicks on a remember me checkbox.

Cookie code

```
if (_model.RememberMe)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("login");
    cookie.Values.Add("username", _model.Username);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

First login code

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(Username,Password))
{
    RememberMe();

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username, false);
}
```

On the first login the Identity.name is set but when I close the browser and go back on to the site. it logs in correctly without the user putting in their credentials but the `Identity.name` is empty.

```
if (Request.Cookies["login"] != null)
{
     // We know the automatic log in has worked as it comes into here...
}
```

What do I need to do once the user by passes the login page so I can setup the `iPrincipal` object?

Thanks

Comment: You can't set `User.Identity.Name` directly, you need to create a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: wow its that simple. thanks that's been doing me in all day. Make it a answer and will mark it if you like

Answer (score 1):

Try below code please
Note : **please check it on page view not in the same method on creation of cokies**

```
private void CreateCokies(string userName)
    {
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, userName);
        string cookieContents = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieContents)
        {
            Expires = authTicket.Expiration,
            Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        };
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```